# Search for matching filename pattern with a bash script

Tags: bash, filenames

First off, I apologize if this is a noob question - I am quite new to bash scripting.

I have a directory containing many types of files and folders. I need to perform a set of actions upon all files matching a certain pattern. This is the pattern: `prefix_suffix.ext`. The `_suffix.ext` is the exact same for all the target files and only the `prefix` portion is variable.

Is it possible (and if so, how?) to, within bash, loop over all filenames matching the pattern and have one variable for `filename` and one for `prefix` within the loop. I'd like to avoid external tools such as `sed`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for filename in *_suffix.ext; do 
    prefix="${filename%_suffix.ext}"
    #do your thing here
done
```

This uses the POSIX suffix stripping feature (see `man dash` and type `/suffix<enter>` to search for `suffix`):

> ${parameter%word}     Remove Smallest Suffix Pattern.  The word is
>   expanded to produce a pattern.  The parameter expansion then results
>   in parameter, with the smallest portion of the suffix matched by the
>   pattern
>                              deleted.

(%% would strip the longest matching suffix, but since we're using a literal suffix here instead of a glob pattern, the two are the same in this case).

**Runnable example:**

```
for filename in pre1_suffix.ext pre2_suffix.ext; do     
       prefix="${filename%_suffix.ext}"
       echo "$prefix"
done
```

will print

```
pre1
pre2
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly - will accept as soon as I'm able.